Deployment validation error issue from SSIS package to SQL server
Deployment validation error issue from SSIS package to SQL server
Something similar to my problem has been posted before but not quite like this. I have Visual Studio 2019 on my Domain server Account. I develop packages with this and deploy the project to SQL Server. The packages run fine. Then I try to validate/deploy and I get the error:

There was an exception while loading Script Task from XML: System.Exception: The Script Task redacted uses version 14.0 script that is not supported in this release of Integration Services. To run the package, use the Script Task to create a new VSTA script. In most cases, scripts are converted automatically to use a supported version, when you open a SQL Server Integration Services package in %SQL_PRODUCT_SHORT_NAME% Integration Services. at Microsoft.SqlServer.Dts.Tasks.ScriptTask.ScriptTask.LoadFromXML (XmlElement elemProj, IDTSInfoEvents events)

Is there a way to fix this issue? are you guys experienced an issue like this one? Please share your expertise, much appreciate your explanation and guidance to surpass this problem.
I tried creating a new Script Task in my SSIS package to replace the one that was giving me version compatibility errors. I copied over the core functionality of my original script into this new task, hoping it would work with my current SSIS version (which I believe is 2019).
I was expecting this approach to resolve the version mismatch issue. The error message mentioned that the script was using version 16.0, which isn't supported in my SSIS release. So by creating a fresh Script Task, I thought it would automatically use a compatible version for my SSIS environment but still loop on the same error page.

If you connect to the target SQL Server with SSMS, or your favourite tool, and execute SELECT @@VERSION; what output do you get? If you go to the properties of the SSIS project what is Configuration Properties > General > TargetServerVersion set to?

Hi Dale K, I fix this issue this afternoon ( I change the TargetServerVersion and set to the latest versin of SSIS and then deployed to my server catalog and when I tried to validate my package its working fine and success.
